# Default Controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, scripting

I am wondering if there is any other configuration options for a default controller.

For example - if I have a controller called "site" and I set the default controller in the following file: application/config/routes.php to:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";
```

I should be able to go to `http://localhost` and that brings up the 
`index();` function in the site controller.

However, if I try to do go to `http://localhost/index.php/index2` to load the `index2();` function I get a 404 error. If I change the URL to `http://localhost/index.php/site/index2` it works fine - but I thought already set the default controller. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it is manually writing the routing rule:

```
$route['index2'] = "site/index2";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.

The default_controller is **only** for URLs without **any** URI parameter. How could CodeIgniter distinguish between a method name and a controller name?

What you can do:
define a redirect inside your 404 document or directly map your 404 document to index.php

Answer (score 0):

No CI doesn't work like that the first parameter has to be the name of a controller, so in this case you would have to create a controlled called "index2".